# getting issue in build after upgrade aws-chime-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I upgrading aws chime 3.6.0 to 3.14.1

after updating package i getting error while building

ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-user-agent/dist-es/user-agent-middleware.js 9:30
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

**Webpack config:**

[image]

**Babelrc config:**

[image]

**Package  Json:**

[image]

I tried various method.

Comment: Hello @Himanshu! Did you finally solve this issue? How did you do? We are having the same issue.

Comment: @AythaNzt yes able to resolve ,all you have to do is delete package-lock file and node_modules , update webpack to v5 and do changes accordingly in webpack config file as maybe it gonna consist deprecated code and reinstall packages